# How to square with only a single starting integer?

Tags: java, arrays

I’m new to programming. I am to make a code that squares the integer. The rules is that:

1. The input consist of only one integer
2. It only loops up to 5 times
3. The output should result with 3 integer places

Below is my desired result:

Input:

```
1
```

Output:

```
001
004
009
016
025
```

Below is my attempted code but it is not working.

```
int start=input.nextInt();

for(int i=5; i <=5; i++; start++){
    num[i]= start*start;
    }
    for (i=0; i<num.length; i++){
        System.out.println(“%03d\n”, num[i]);
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this. Ideone link https://www.ideone.com/IzO18y

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
 
 
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
 
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.printf("%03d\n",n*n);
            n+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputNum = sacnner.nextInt();
int loopTimes = 0;
While(loopTimes < 5 , loopTimes++){
       System.out.println("%30d\n", inputNum*inputNum);
       inputNum += 1
   }
```